# How to apply style to a class or id with changing index?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have style like this:

```css
#detailTable4 tbody tr td:last-child {
  background-color: #7E0303;
}
```

I would like to apply this to all elements with **#detailTable** (no matter of the index 1,2...# a the end). Is it possible to do it just with CSS?

Comment: Do you want to apply all descendant of #detailTable or just tds?

Comment: Why don't you use a `class`?

Comment: `[id^="detailTable"]`

Comment: use a common `class` for those tables. and apply your style

Comment: I can't use class because I call tables by ids, it depends which I need (I'm using nested tables etc.)

Comment: I hadn't removed the jQuery tag (even though this could be done with just CSS) because the question asks for a jQuery way also. If you are OK with it, you could remove that sentence and jQuery tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `id` starts with attribute selector like in the below snippet. The `[id^="detailTable"]` selector would match any element whose `id` starts with `detailTable`.

```css
[id^="detailTable"] tbody tr td:last-child {
  background-color: #7E0303;
}
```

```html
<table id='detailTable1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id='detailTable2'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id='detailTable4'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id='detailTable-abcd'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use id start with selector:

```
[id^="detailTable"] tbody tr td:last-child {
  background-color: #7E0303;
}
```

Comment: I just realized what his question is.

Answer (score 0):

```
[id^=detailTable] tbody tr td:last-child {
  background-color: #7E0303;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: That is because three people were answering it at the same time before the browser got refreshed to notice other peoples answers @Mr.Alien

Comment: Not sure but StackOverflow does notify you when someone drops in an answer while you are writing your own.